# Integer is not being updated

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game that includes a high score label that comes up once the player dies, along with a restart button. Overall the high score, which is an integer, works fine but there is one problem. If you reach a new high score in that round you just finished you have to die again for it to show the new high score. Lets say I play the game while the high score is already 15 and I score 17 when the high score label comes up it still shows 15. After I restart the game and the high score comes up again it will now show 17. The high score is not updating when I want it to.

```
import SpriteKit

struct physicsCatagory {
    static let person : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let Ice : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let IceTwo : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    static let IceThree : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
    static let Score : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var Highscore = Int()
    var timeOfLastSpawn: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
    var timePerSpawn: CFTimeInterval = 1.2
    var scorenumber = Int()
    var lifenumber = Int()
    var SpeedNumber : Double = 0.5
    var person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Person1")
    let Score = SKSpriteNode()
    var ScoreLable = SKLabelNode()
    var Highscorelabel = SKLabelNode()
    let BackGround = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "BackGround")
    var restartButton = SKSpriteNode()
    var Died = Bool()

    func restartScene(){
        self.removeAllChildren()
        self.removeAllActions()
        scorenumber = 0
        lifenumber = 0
        createScene()
        random()
        //spawnThirdIce()
        Died = false
        timeOfLastSpawn = 0.0
        timePerSpawn = 1.2
    }

    func createScene(){
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        if (scorenumber > Highscore){
            var Highscoredefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            Highscoredefault.setValue(scorenumber, forKey: "HighScore")
        }

        var Highscoredefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if (Highscoredefault.valueForKey("HighScore") != nil){
            Highscore = Highscoredefault.valueForKey("HighScore") as! NSInteger
        }
        else{
            Highscore = 0
        }

        lifenumber = 0
        SpeedNumber = 1

        BackGround.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        BackGround.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
        BackGround.zPosition = -5
        self.addChild(BackGround)

        Score.size = CGSize(width: 2563, height: 1)
        Score.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: -20)
        Score.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Score.size)
        Score.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Score.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Score.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.Score
        Score.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        Score.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.IceThree
        Score.color = SKColor.blueColor()
        Score.zPosition = -5
        self.addChild(Score)

        person.zPosition = 1
        person.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/9.5)
        person.setScale(0.6)
        person.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 50))
        person.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        person.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.person
        person.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.Ice
        person.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCatagory.Ice
        person.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        person.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                self.addChild(person)

        ScoreLable = SKLabelNode()
        ScoreLable.fontName = "Arial"
        ScoreLable.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 1700)
        ScoreLable.text = "\(scorenumber)"
        ScoreLable.fontColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        ScoreLable.fontSize = 150
        self.addChild(ScoreLable)

        Highscorelabel.fontName = "Arial"
        Highscorelabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 1400)
        Highscorelabel.text = "HighScore: \(Highscore)"
        Highscorelabel.fontSize = 150
        Highscorelabel.fontColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        Highscorelabel.zPosition = -7
        self.addChild(Highscorelabel)
    }

    func random() -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    }

    func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return random() * (max - min) + min
    }

    var gameArea: CGRect

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
        let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
        let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
        gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

        super.init(size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        createScene()
    }

    func createButton(){
        restartButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Restart Button")
        restartButton.position = CGPoint(x: 768, y: 1024)
        restartButton.zPosition = 6
        restartButton.setScale(2.3)
        self.addChild(restartButton)
    }

     func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            let firstBody = contact.bodyA
            let secondBody = contact.bodyB

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.person && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree || firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.person{

           scorenumber++

            if scorenumber == 20 {
              timePerSpawn = 1.0
            }
            if scorenumber == 40{
                timePerSpawn = 0.89
            }
            if scorenumber == 60{

                timePerSpawn = 0.6
            }
            if scorenumber == 80{
                timePerSpawn = 0.5
            }
            if scorenumber == 100{
                timePerSpawn = 0.4
            }
            if scorenumber == 120{
                timePerSpawn = 0.3
            }

            ScoreLable.text = "\(scorenumber)"
            CollisionWithPerson(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Person: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)  
        }

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Score && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree ||
            firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.IceThree && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.Score{
                lifenumber++

                if lifenumber == 1{
                    //person.texture
                    person.texture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Flower#2")
                }
                if lifenumber == 2{
            person.texture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Flower#3")
        }
                if lifenumber == 3{
                   // self.addChild(Highscorelabel)
                    Highscorelabel.zPosition = 5
                    createButton()
                    person.zPosition = -6
                    person.texture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Person1")
                    //person.removeFromParent()
                    Died = true
                }
        }
    }

    func CollisionWithPerson (Ice: SKSpriteNode, Person: SKSpriteNode){
      Person.removeFromParent()

       // if (scorenumber > Highscore){
         //   var Highscoredefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
           // Highscoredefault.setValue(scorenumber, forKey: "HighScore")

        //} 
    }

    func spawnThirdIce(){
        if Died == true {
        } else
        {

        var Ice = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ice")
        Ice.zPosition = 2
        Ice.setScale(1.5)
        Ice.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Ice.size)
        Ice.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.IceThree
        Ice.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.person | physicsCatagory.Score
        Ice.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Ice.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

        let randomXStart = random(min:CGRectGetMinX(gameArea), max: CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))
        let randomXend = random(min:CGRectGetMinX(gameArea),max: CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea))

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
        let endpoint = CGPoint(x: randomXend, y: -self.size.height * 0.2)
        Ice.position = startPoint
        let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(endpoint, duration: 2.0)
        let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let enemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy , deleteEnemy])
        Ice.runAction(enemySequence)

        self.addChild(Ice)
        }
    }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch in touches{
                let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

                if Died == true{
                    if restartButton.containsPoint(location){
                        restartScene()
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if Died == true {
        }
        else{
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousTouch = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
            let ammountDragged = location.x - previousTouch.x

            person.position.x += ammountDragged

            if person.position.x > CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - person.size.width/2{
                person.position.x = CGRectGetMaxX(gameArea) - person.size.width/2
            }

                if person.position.x <  CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + person.size.width/2{
                    person.position.x = CGRectGetMinX(gameArea) + person.size.width/2

            }
            }
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        if (currentTime - timeOfLastSpawn > timePerSpawn) {
            spawnThirdIce()
            self.timeOfLastSpawn = currentTime
        }
    }
}
```

Ok this is what I added to if life number = 3:

```
if lifenumber == 3{

                                 if (scorenumber > Highscore){
            var Highscoredefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            Highscoredefault.setValue(scorenumber, forKey: "HighScore")

        }


        var Highscoredefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if (Highscoredefault.valueForKey("HighScore") != nil){

            Highscore = Highscoredefault.valueForKey("HighScore") as! NSInteger
        }
        else{
            Highscore = 0

        }
                    self.addChild(Highscorelabel)
                    createButton()
                    person.zPosition = -6
                    person.texture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "Person1")
                    Died = true
                }
```

Comment: You should think about using a `switch` for all those `if` statements, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html.

Comment: @DanielStorm Ok thanks I will look into switch statements from what I have just seen they look like they might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must add just this:

after `scorenumber++` in `func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)`

```
//ADD THIS
if scorenumber > Highscore {
    Highscore = scorenumber 
    Highscorelabel.text = "HighScore: \(Highscore)"
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try that and will tell you if it worked later today.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. The high score now updates whenever the game is running thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you only set the `text` property of `Highscorelabel` when you initialize it. If you want the `Highscorelabel` to be updated immediately upon death then you should update it at such time.

```
if lifenumber == 3 {
/* Check if new highscore, update HighscoreLabel */
```

Comment: That is definitely the problem, thanks. But Im not sure how I can check for the new high score and make the label update. Can you tell me how I would do (implement) this.

Comment: @james create an `if` statement to see if the new score is higher than the previous high score. If it is then update the label. This is the correct answer to your problem and you should accept it.

Comment: @DanielStorm Ok I added the if statement, you can see what I did at the bottom of my question above. But it is still not working for some reason. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @cocojoe I added what I did to the question above but it still is not working.